# How to hide a QWidget when mouse clicked on out side that widget

Tags: qt

I want hide a QWidget when mouse clicks out of that widget just like it have a popup flag:

```cpp
auto widget = new QWidget(this);
widget->setWindowFlag(Qt::Popup); // this widget will hide, when mouse click out of that widget.
```

For some reason, I can't set **these flags** and must implement some thing myself which behaves like this.

Or can I get a mouse event out of that widget?

**Solution**:

As I said, I can't use Qt flags and have to implement the similar behavior myself.My solution is [installEventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to `QApplication`, in the override method [eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter),I filter the [QMouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html)  and send a signal.

Comment: It depend's where does the click occur: outside the widget, but on other widget of the same application, or outside of all application's widgets.

Comment: @vahancho On other widget of the same application.

Comment: You might handle click on other widgets too, either by overriding their event handling functions or by installing an event filter on all widgets.

Comment: `widget->setWindowFlag(Qt::Popup);` works for me (on Debian with Qt 5.7 ). What is your OS and Qt version ?

Comment: @vahancho thank you ,but there are too many widgets.

Comment: @Scab That works fine for me too, but I just can't use this due to some other issues, I have to implement such things myself.

Comment: use `Qt :: FramelessWindowHint | Qt :: Tool`

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan I can't use Qt flags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get a mouse event out of the widget.

Make a custom widget and reimplement mousePressEvent, which will catch the last click (the ouside-the-widget click that hides the "popup"). But be careful to add the call to QWidget::mousePressEvent(event) in the end, otherwise the last click will be lost and your widget will remain onscreen.

```
CustomWidget::CutomWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
}

void CustomWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  if (!this->underMouse()) {
  //if the click is not on the widget, i.e. if it's the click that hides it,
  // you caught it, do what you want to do here.
  }
  QWidget::mousePressEvent(event); 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, however, as I said, I can't use flags like `Qt::Popup`, I must implement something like this myself.

Comment: You're welcome. I am curious as to why you can't use flags?

Comment: @maidamai If you cannot use the flag, you should be able to close the widget yourself by calling `close()`.